# C++ promise.set_value fails with unknown error under linux

Tags: c++, c++11, future

I'm trying to get my simulation running on our high performance server. It (unfortunately) uses CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core) instead of Win10, under which I'm developing the program. With this came a large amount of errors, one of them I was not able to fix on my on:

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argument_count, char** arguments) {
    int i = 1234;
    std::cout << "Initialized i" << std::endl;

    std::promise<int> promise;
    std::cout << "Constructed promise" << std::endl;

    promise.set_value(std::move(i));
    std::cout << "Set value" << std::endl;

    std::future<int> future = std::move(promise.get_future());
    std::cout << "Retrieved future" << std::endl;

    int j = std::move(future.get());
    std::cout << "Got value: " << j << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling this under Win10 with "cl test.cpp", the output looks like I'd expect:

> Desktop>test.exe
>
> Initialized i
>
> Constructed promise
>
> Set value
>
> Retrieved future
>
> Got value: 1234

On the other hand, when compiling on the server with "g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp", the output is different:

> ~/test_dir$ ./a.out
>
> Initialized i
>
> Constructed promise
>
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
>
> what():  Unknown error -1
>
> Aborted

I do get the same error when trying this with an Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS machine. I don't see why this happens.
Obviously, something is fishy in this line: `promise.set_value(std::move(i))` since the output before is printed and the line after that statement is not executed any more. Furthermore, the compiler/ linker does find a one of the two versions "void set_value (const T& val);" or "void set_value (T&& val);" that would be appropriate for the template specification "int", i strongly suspect the later.

But why is the program aborting when setting an integer as the value of a promise? Even when inlining the value and skipping the variable all together does produce the error.

Can someone point me to where the error is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try compiling using the `pthread` flag:

`g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -pthread`

Comment: That fixed the issue. Can you elaborate on that? Why does one have to include non-standard compiler flags for pure standard behaviour? As far as I understand the issue, this suggests to the compiler/linker that within the program, there is usage of multithreading stuff and thus the pthread library ist required. Why doesn't a compile time error appear if this flag is absense?

Comment: It's because of gthreads, a layer of abstraction around pthreads, std::thread only knows when threads are not available at run time. Also, the compilation (let alone linking) process isn't covered by the C++ standard. Inconvenient, yes, but one should simply know. Also see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52681

Comment: Agree, it is counterintuitive. You have to understand that `<future>` uses `<thread>` which is a relatively high level of abstraction defined in the C++ standard. However how `<thread>` is implemented depends on the OS, i.e. the libraries may differ. If your problem is resolved, can you mark the response as *accepted*?

Answer (score 0):

Linking against both `pthread` and `stdc++` may resolve the issue.
Example adding `stdc++` in Cmake:

```
    target_link_libraries(
        # Your library or binary here
        stdc++
        pthread
    )
```

Tested with the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    static_cast<void>(argc);
    static_cast<void>(argv);

    std::promise<int> pr;
    auto fut = pr.get_future();
    pr.set_value(10);
    std::cout << fut.get() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```